# How do I stop my mini schauzer from eating non food items while on walks?

Tags: dogs, eating

My mini schnauzer (10 months old) literally tries to eat everything when we are out on a walk. We've removed bottle caps, napkins, wood chunks,stones, you name it!!!! I've tried many things to stop him...but it seems of no use.I use the "Leave It" command, tried just a simple no, all while pulling up on his harness.... What is going on with him? My husband is on the verge of giving him up..

Answer (score 0):

At 10 months, the pup may be teething. He's also young enough that he is still learning the world. Humans that age will put everything in their mouths for the same reason... And remember that a dog's mouth is also as close as it comes to having hands.

You wanted a puppy, you got a puppy. He'll grow out of it.

Meanwhile, some toys specifically intended to be chewed on might help.

(I don't know whether dogs can develop pica. One of my cats seems to have a mild case thereof ; he insists on trying to ingest strings and dust bunnies. I control his access to string -- if it's thick enough he'll just try to chew it into pieces, which is much safer -- but the dust bunnies are on their own.)